# Filter array of 'objects with nested objects' using ES6 arrow functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How can i filter an array of objects like the one down below based on the **'id'** or the **'subdivisions.id'**

ps: the **id**s are unique and you can not find object.id == object.subdivisions[n].id

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "South East",
  "subdivisions": [
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Berkshire"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Buckinghamshire"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "East Sussex"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "Hampshire"
    },
    {
      "id": "6",
      "name": "Isle of Wight"
    },
    {
      "id": "7",
      "name": "Kent"
    },
    {
      "id": "8",
      "name": "Oxfordshire"
    },
    {
      "id": "9",
      "name": "Surrey"
    },
    {
      "id": "10",
      "name": "West Sussex"
    }
  ]
}
```

and get as a result a simple object like this:

```
{
  "id": "10",
  "name": "West Sussex"
}
```

**Edit**

here is the full array:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "South East",
    "subdivisions": [
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Berkshire",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Buckinghamshire",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "East Sussex",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "5",
        "name": "Hampshire",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "6",
        "name": "Isle of Wight",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "7",
        "name": "Kent",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "8",
        "name": "Oxfordshire",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "9",
        "name": "Surrey",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "10",
        "name": "West Sussex",
        "__typename": "Region"
      }
    ],
    "__typename": "Region"
  },
  {
    "id": "11",
    "name": "London",
    "subdivisions": [
      {
        "id": "12",
        "name": "City of London",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "13",
        "name": "City of Westminster",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "14",
        "name": "Kensington and Chelsea",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "15",
        "name": "Hammersmith and Fulham",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "16",
        "name": "Wandsworth",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "17",
        "name": "Lambeth",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "18",
        "name": "Southwark",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "19",
        "name": "Tower Hamlets",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "20",
        "name": "Hackney",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "21",
        "name": "Islington",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "22",
        "name": "Camden",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "23",
        "name": "Brent",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "24",
        "name": "Ealing",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "25",
        "name": "Hounslow",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "26",
        "name": "Richmond",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "27",
        "name": "Kingston",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "28",
        "name": "Merton",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "29",
        "name": "Sutton",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "30",
        "name": "Croydon",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "31",
        "name": "Bromley",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "32",
        "name": "Lewisham",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "33",
        "name": "Greenwich",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "34",
        "name": "Bexley",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "35",
        "name": "Havering",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "36",
        "name": "Barking and Dagenham",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "37",
        "name": "Redbridge",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "38",
        "name": "Newham",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "39",
        "name": "Waltham Forest",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "40",
        "name": "Haringey",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "41",
        "name": "Enfield",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "42",
        "name": "Barnet",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "43",
        "name": "Harrow",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "44",
        "name": "Hillingdon",
        "__typename": "Region"
      }
    ],
    "__typename": "Region"
  },
  {
    "id": "45",
    "name": "North West England",
    "subdivisions": [
      {
        "id": "46",
        "name": "Cheshire",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "47",
        "name": "Cumbria",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "48",
        "name": "Greater Manchester",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "49",
        "name": "Lancashire",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "50",
        "name": "Merseyside",
        "__typename": "Region"
      }
    ],
    "__typename": "Region"
  },
  {
    "id": "51",
    "name": "East of England",
    "subdivisions": [
      {
        "id": "52",
        "name": "East Anglia",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "53",
        "name": "Bedfordshire and Hertfordshire",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "54",
        "name": "Essex",
        "__typename": "Region"
      }
    ],
    "__typename": "Region"
  },
  {
    "id": "55",
    "name": "West Midlands",
    "subdivisions": [
      {
        "id": "56",
        "name": "Herefordshire, Worcestershire and Warwickshire",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "57",
        "name": "Shropshire and Staffordshire",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "58",
        "name": "West Midlands",
        "__typename": "Region"
      }
    ],
    "__typename": "Region"
  },
  {
    "id": "59",
    "name": "South West England",
    "subdivisions": [
      {
        "id": "60",
        "name": "Gloucestershire, Wiltshire and Bristol/Bath area",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "61",
        "name": "Dorset and Somerset",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "62",
        "name": "Cornwall and Isles of Scilly",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "63",
        "name": "Devon",
        "__typename": "Region"
      }
    ],
    "__typename": "Region"
  },
  {
    "id": "64",
    "name": "Yorkshire and the Humber",
    "subdivisions": [
      {
        "id": "65",
        "name": "East Riding and North Lincolnshire",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "66",
        "name": "North Yorkshire",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "67",
        "name": "South Yorkshire",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "68",
        "name": "West Yorkshire",
        "__typename": "Region"
      }
    ],
    "__typename": "Region"
  },
  {
    "id": "69",
    "name": "East Midlands",
    "subdivisions": [
      {
        "id": "70",
        "name": "Derbyshire and Nottinghamshire",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "71",
        "name": "Leicestershire, Rutland and Northamptonshire",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "72",
        "name": "Lincolnshire",
        "__typename": "Region"
      }
    ],
    "__typename": "Region"
  },
  {
    "id": "73",
    "name": "North East England",
    "subdivisions": [
      {
        "id": "74",
        "name": "Tees Valley and County Durham",
        "__typename": "Region"
      },
      {
        "id": "75",
        "name": "Northumberland and Tyne and Wear",
        "__typename": "Region"
      }
    ],
    "__typename": "Region"
  }
]
```

Comment: why is `1` equal to `10`?

Comment: Why do you have the requirement "with ES6 arrow function"?  Sounds like homework.

Comment: @NinaScholz, no, s/he means that IDs are unique, 1 **is not equal** to 10

Comment: @lucifer63, but it needs some kind of value for comparison ...?

Comment: @NinaScholz, he just wanted to say that there will be no equal IDs at all nesting levels)

Comment: and what are you actually looking for?

Comment: @NinaScholz , it's like recursively search for the **id** in both object[i].id and object[i].subdivisions[j].id and then get as a result an object with the **id** and **name** properties.

Comment: please add some search parameters and the wanted result form the above data.

Comment: i'm using react, i get a location **id** from the url, and i should display some results based on the region (object[i].id) or more specifically based on the city (object[i].subdivisions[j].id) .

and the purpose of this question is that i need both the 'name' and the 'id' so i can update my filter .

the url can be in one of these formats: 
  /search/location-name-id/category-name-id
  /search/location-name-id
  /search/category-name-id

both location & category are in the same data structure (hence this is why i need both **name** and **id**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for it.

```
let result =  object.subdivisions.find(sub => sub.id === id);
```

For a search either outside or in `subdivisions`, you could use the following

```js
function find(data, id) {
    var result = data.find(o => o.id === id);
    if (!result) {
        data.some(o => result = o.subdivisions.find(s => s.id === id));
    }
    return result;
}

var data = [{ id: "1", name: "South East", subdivisions: [{ id: "2", name: "Berkshire", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "3", name: "Buckinghamshire", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "4", name: "East Sussex", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "5", name: "Hampshire", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "6", name: "Isle of Wight", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "7", name: "Kent", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "8", name: "Oxfordshire", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "9", name: "Surrey", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "10", name: "West Sussex", __typename: "Region" }], __typename: "Region" }, { id: "11", name: "London", subdivisions: [{ id: "12", name: "City of London", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "13", name: "City of Westminster", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "14", name: "Kensington and Chelsea", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "15", name: "Hammersmith and Fulham", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "16", name: "Wandsworth", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "17", name: "Lambeth", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "18", name: "Southwark", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "19", name: "Tower Hamlets", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "20", name: "Hackney", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "21", name: "Islington", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "22", name: "Camden", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "23", name: "Brent", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "24", name: "Ealing", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "25", name: "Hounslow", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "26", name: "Richmond", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "27", name: "Kingston", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "28", name: "Merton", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "29", name: "Sutton", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "30", name: "Croydon", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "31", name: "Bromley", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "32", name: "Lewisham", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "33", name: "Greenwich", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "34", name: "Bexley", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "35", name: "Havering", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "36", name: "Barking and Dagenham", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "37", name: "Redbridge", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "38", name: "Newham", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "39", name: "Waltham Forest", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "40", name: "Haringey", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "41", name: "Enfield", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "42", name: "Barnet", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "43", name: "Harrow", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "44", name: "Hillingdon", __typename: "Region" }], __typename: "Region" }, { id: "45", name: "North West England", subdivisions: [{ id: "46", name: "Cheshire", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "47", name: "Cumbria", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "48", name: "Greater Manchester", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "49", name: "Lancashire", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "50", name: "Merseyside", __typename: "Region" }], __typename: "Region" }, { id: "51", name: "East of England", subdivisions: [{ id: "52", name: "East Anglia", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "53", name: "Bedfordshire and Hertfordshire", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "54", name: "Essex", __typename: "Region" }], __typename: "Region" }, { id: "55", name: "West Midlands", subdivisions: [{ id: "56", name: "Herefordshire, Worcestershire and Warwickshire", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "57", name: "Shropshire and Staffordshire", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "58", name: "West Midlands", __typename: "Region" }], __typename: "Region" }, { id: "59", name: "South West England", subdivisions: [{ id: "60", name: "Gloucestershire, Wiltshire and Bristol/Bath area", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "61", name: "Dorset and Somerset", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "62", name: "Cornwall and Isles of Scilly", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "63", name: "Devon", __typename: "Region" }], __typename: "Region" }, { id: "64", name: "Yorkshire and the Humber", subdivisions: [{ id: "65", name: "East Riding and North Lincolnshire", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "66", name: "North Yorkshire", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "67", name: "South Yorkshire", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "68", name: "West Yorkshire", __typename: "Region" }], __typename: "Region" }, { id: "69", name: "East Midlands", subdivisions: [{ id: "70", name: "Derbyshire and Nottinghamshire", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "71", name: "Leicestershire, Rutland and Northamptonshire", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "72", name: "Lincolnshire", __typename: "Region" }], __typename: "Region" }, { id: "73", name: "North East England", subdivisions: [{ id: "74", name: "Tees Valley and County Durham", __typename: "Region" }, { id: "75", name: "Northumberland and Tyne and Wear", __typename: "Region" }], __typename: "Region" }];

console.log(find(data, 'foo')); // undefined
console.log(find(data, '66'));  // item from subdivisions
console.log(find(data, '69'));  // item from outer array
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: but the 'object' is an array of objects

Comment: please add the complete data structure with only some data to get the idea of the problem.

Comment: i added the full array so you can understand what i meant

Comment: thank you so much. it's working, i'm just getting an ESlint error on the 4th line: Arrow function should not return assignment. if you can help with that ?

Comment: i don't get that error, but you coukd use a comma operator, like `data.some(o => (result = o.subdivisions.find(s => s.id === id), result));`